# In JavaScript ES6, how do I take just a few properties from a hash?

Tags: javascript, properties, ecmascript-6, clone, destructuring

I have an object with some properties. I would like to extract a few well-know properties, skipping over any that are not present.

Something like this:

```
let x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
let y = take a, b, d from x; // Not real JS!
```

With `y` now looking like this:

```
{a: 1, b: 2} // Note that d is missing!
```

Is there an operator or method that does this?

Comment: You could do `delete in.c`. But not sure if that's what you want, since it also deletes it from in. You could also clone and then delete c.

Comment: please do not use `in` for a variable name, because its a operator.

Comment: Deleting `c` does not work because there may be properties `d, e, f...`

Comment: I have updated the example to use `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it is by destructuring:

```
let {a, b, d} = x;
let y = {a, b, d};
```

This automatically takes out the properties you want to use.
Then you can put them back together with an object literal, which in ES6 doesn't require you to do `{ a: a, b : b }`. You can just write `{ a, b }` instead, if the names are the same.

In this case, `a`, `b` and `d` are also copied.

Comment: And it also pollutes your scope with unnecessary variables :P

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
out = {a: in.a, b:in.b, d:in.d};
out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(out));
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(out));` ?

Comment: It's there to remove any property that is undefined.

Comment: I see... that might be worth pointing out, as well as the drawbacks of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var copied = {};
var propertiesToCopy = ['a', 'b'];
for (var key in originalObject) {
  if (originalObject.hasOwnProperty(key) && propertiesToCopy.indexOf(key) != -1) {
    copied[key] = originalObject[key];
  }
}
```